# ASP.NET MVC NESTED Virtual Directory for Content Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, virtual-directory

I'm trying to map a virtual directory in my ASP.NET MVC 3 website.  The virtual directory contains image files only, and the physical directory is located on another server.  When I try to access an image from this directory via a web browser, I get an HTTP 500 error:

```
Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '<virtual directory path>' because access is denied.
```

[EDIT]: After restarting IIS, I see that it's added "access is denied" to the end of the error message.  However, the directory has the "Everyone" permission on it with read-access and it's still not working.  I've seen posts that detail this same error, but the permission-setting solution isn't working for me.

Why is it looking for a configuration file?  I've updated my Global.asax to ignore the route in question, and from within IIS 6, I can browse the files located in the virtual directory without issue.  I've verified that the virtual directory is NOT set up as an application.  Also, the permissions on the directory have read access for Everyone set.  What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT #2]: The virtual directory being pointed to is a network shared folder...  Does that make any difference?

[EDIT #3]: The IIS 6 hierarchy for what I'm trying to do is this: Default Website -> OurSite (MVC website which is ITSELF a virtual directory) -> Images (virtual directory that I'm struggling with). There definitely is a problem with the fact that this is a nested virtual directory; if I create the directory as a direct child of Default Website instead of Default Website -> OurSite, it works fine.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the identity running the App Pool also has execute and list permissions on that virtual folder as it's trying to monitor it for changes for caching.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316721/

[EDIT] This link indicates it may be the second case where it's not having permissions to a subfolder in the shared directory.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317955

Does the ASPNET account have access all the way down that tree?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately that isn't working for me.  The app pool that the site is running under is using identity: "NETWORK SERVICE" and I've added permissions for that specific user at both the website level and the virtual directory level.  The link you sent says that if the "Everyone" user has access, then you shouldn't need to add the app pool user, but now, both users have access and it's still not working.

Comment: Saw another KB article that implies that it may be deeper in the directory path for that shared drive. You may see what identities are accessing that share OK in the subfolders.

Comment: I've made sure that the entire hierarchy of the shared folder has permissions granted to NETWORK SERVICE, IUSR_machinename, and ASPNET, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: OK - so the virtual directory I created exists as a child of the website which ITSELF is a virtual directory under "Default Website".  If I create the virtual directory directly under "Default Website" then it works fine.  Why can't you do nested virtual directories?

Comment: That is a very good question, especially since the VD is contained within its own web folder.  I wonder if it's resolving the path properly. The contents of "virtual directory path" on the error message above were hidden, was it showing the proper expanded path on the actual error message?

Comment: Yes, it reported the path to the network share: \\server\e$\directory.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Turnkey's answer and your comments, I just wanted to point out that if your AppPool is using `NETWORK SERVICE` identity then your remote server needs to add the web server's **machine/computer account** to the shared folder and NTFS permissions **NOT** the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.
If you add `NETWORK SERVICE` to the shared folder and NTFS permissions, you are just adding the *local machine*'s `NETWORK SERVICE` account not the *web server*'s `NETWORK SERVICE` account. I hope I am making sense.
Whenever you use a computer's `NETWORK SERVICE` account to connect remotely you are in effect using the computer's **machine account** so that's what you need to add.
Say your web server is called **PRODSERVER**, you need to add the machine/computer account **PRODSERVER$** to the remote shared folder's permissions.
Hope that helps.